# Transparent png image is not fully transparent in browser

Tags: css, png

I am using Chrome browser. I have a fully transparent `.png` image for logo, but there seems to be a problem:

[image]

You need to look quite a second time but as you can see the image has a lighter tint than the background. I create the background with CSS:

```css
background: #e1e2e4;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top,
            left bottom, from(#e1e2e4), to(#8f9094));

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e1e2e4,  #8f9094);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
        (startColorstr='#e1e2e4', endColorstr='#8f9094'); 

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Any ideas why this happens? How can I solve this?

Comment: I really can't see it... Is the PNG saved in 24-Bit?

Comment: Probably the image has a very slight opacity over the whole background. Have you tried going into Photoshop (or equivalent), selecting the background, deleting it and resaving the image out?

Comment: Are you sure the color difference is not part of the background gradient?

Comment: I have this file in photoshop, there is no layer above it. It's PNG RGB COLOR 8 BIT/CHANNEL

Comment: @feeela--I would concur. ArtWorkAD, have you set the background-color to a _solid_ color and tested to see if you see the same result? The color shift could very well be the change point of color for the gradient you set in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with color profiles and color correction. See [this article](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/) for more detail.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem in Chrome. The article says "PNG’s can be tagged in three different ways. First they can have an iCCP chunk that contains the associated ICC profile. Second they can be explicitly tagged as sRGB using a sRGB chunk. Finally, they can contain gAMA and cHRM chunks that describe the image’s gamma and chromaticies. Using any of these methods will cause Firefox to color correct the image. [...] Use TweakPNG and delete the gAMA, cHRM, iCCP and sRGB chunks by hand." -- I did that, and I still see the effect.

Answer (score 3):

Easy fix that seems to work ..

- Download and run GIMP.
- Open your PNG file.
- From the main menu select Image -> Mode -> Indexed.
- Save / Overwrite your PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with a transparent PNG loaded in a `div` with a `background-color:red` via markdown (reveal.js), but the transparent pixels were showing up lighter than the red color:

[image]

The lighter red is the transparent PNG (and the white in lower left is part of a logo).

As it turns out, `reveal.js` loads markdown images (with the `beige` theme at least) with a white background with 0.12 alpha:

```css
.reveal section img {
    ...
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
    ...
}
```

Deactivating it in the Inspect feature of Chrome developer tools made the problem go away.

I finally solved it in my markdown by styling the image with a background-color the same as my `div`

```
![The logo](logo_with_transparent_background.png){class=plain style="background-color:red"}
```