# Somehow a transparent image is showing a slight background color

Tags: html, css, image

See the below screenshot, I have an image. This image definitely has a transparent background. Looks fine on a bright background like orange, but you can see the browser has applied it's own background on the gray.

I've never seen anything like this before, confirmed happening in chrome, firefox, edge and brave:

[image]

[image]

### Edit

Just so you can see what I'm looking at in the graphics design package

[image]

Comment: Either the png actually has a slight bg (in that case open it in Photoshop or Photopea) and try applying the eraser in that area, or it could be due to the color format. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739462/transparent-png-image-is-not-fully-transparent-in-browser and https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/ for more info

Comment: @elveti - thanks for the reply. Definitely transparent background. Not heard of color correction before but I'm amazed this is an issue. I basically, for whatever reason, can't use a grey background if my images have transparency. That's bonkers.